# How to use a if statements in the within command of R programming language

Tags: r

Here is my data frame:

df:

```
TYPE X RESULT
A    1  UNKNOWN
B    9  UNKNOWN
A    5  UNKNOWN
B    11 UNKNOWN
A    30 UNKNOWN
```

I need to update the RESULT column in my dataframe. This column should have the value **LOW** if the value of the X field of the dataframe is lower than a threshold  and **NORMAL** otherwise.

For example:

```
threshold = 10
```

df:

```
TYPE X RESULT
A    1  LOW
B    9  LOW
A    5  LOW
B    11 NORMAL
A    30 NORMAL
```

I'm trying to accomplish that with this script:

```
threshold = 10   
df = within(df,{RESULT<- if(X <= threshold ) "LOW"  else "NORMAL" })
```

But it is not working.

I'm receiving this warning:

*the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.*

Additionally I need to know how to apply the within expression only on some rows. For example, I need to calculate the RESULT column only on the lines where the type is equals to A. All the lines with the type B must remain  "*untouched*".

.

R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)

Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Nice to see the use of `within`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question is answered by link posted by @H 1. You need to use `ifelse` since `X` is a vector and `if` is used to apply only on scalar input

```
df$RESULT <- ifelse(df$X <= threshold, "LOW", "NORMAL")

df
#  TYPE  X RESULT
#1    A  1    LOW
#2    B  9    LOW
#3    A  5    LOW
#4    B 11 NORMAL
#5    A 30 NORMAL
```

You can still use `if` but you might need a `for` loop and iterate over each value one by one.

For second part, you need to subset values for `TYPE`

```
df$RESULT[df$TYPE == "A"] <- ifelse(df$X[df$TYPE == "A"] <= threshold, "LOW", "NORMAL")

df
#  TYPE  X  RESULT
#1    A  1     LOW
#2    B  9 UNKNOWN
#3    A  5     LOW
#4    B 11 UNKNOWN
#5    A 30  NORMAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option without any `ifelse`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[TYPE == "A", RESULT := c("NORMAL", "LOW")[(X <= threshold) + 1]]
df
#    TYPE  X  RESULT
#1:    A  1     LOW
#2:    B  9 UNKNOWN
#3:    A  5     LOW
#4:    B 11 UNKNOWN
#5:    A 30  NORMAL
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(TYPE = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), X = c(1L, 9L, 
5L, 11L, 30L), RESULT = c("UNKNOWN", "UNKNOWN", "UNKNOWN", "UNKNOWN", 
 "UNKNOWN")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```